# eloquent returning different year results when using carbon for wherebetween

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Laravel eloquent is returning wrong results with eloquent query when using carbon for dates.

this is what i did

```
$start = '2020-12-04';
$end = '2020-12-24';

return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'user_id', 'id')
                    ->whereBetween('created_at', 
                        [new \Illuminate\Support\Carbon(self::$start), 
                         new \Illuminate\Support\Carbon(self::$end)]);
```

and the results will include different years so long the date is the same so i would get back in the result dates that are between 2019-12-04, - 2019-12-24 and between 2020-12-04, - 2020-12-24

how can i fix this

Comment: are $start and $end static members of your class?

Answer (score 0):

Try your query without carbon

```
$start = '2020-12-04';
$end = '2020-12-24';

return $this->hasMany('App\Transaction', 'user_id', 'id')
            ->whereBetween(\DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), [$start, $end]);
```